# Polynomial roots with sum of coefficients prime

Tags: polynomials

*There exists a quadratic polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients such that: (a) both of its roots are positive integers, (b) the sum of its coefficients is prime, and (c) for some integer k, $P(k) = −55$. Show that one of its roots is $2$, and find the other root.*

This is a problem from **Canada 2001**. I found this on a note by **Adeel Khan**.

My process is, Let the roots be $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. By the second condition, we have
$$a(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)=\pm p\text{ for some prime }p$$
Clearly, $a,b$ are distinct, otherwise it violates the third condition. Therefore, one of them is $2$ (WLOG $\alpha=2$) and $a=\pm1$.
If $a=1$, $$(1-\beta)=p\implies\beta=1-p$$
$$b=-(\alpha+\beta)=p-3$$
$$c=\alpha\beta=2-2p$$
hence, $$P(2)=4a+2b+c=4a+2p-6+2-2p=4a+4(p-1)=0\implies p-1=a=1\implies p=2\implies\beta=-1$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore $a=-1$.

Tell me if I have done any mistake and what to do next.

Comment: **Correction:** $a=1-p=1$ leads to a contradiction. That's not $p-1$.

Comment: Did you mean to write "Clearly $\alpha$, $\beta$ are unique"?  instead of $a,b$?  I don't see how you conclude that $a,b$ are distinct...

Comment: I think what you have done so far (with the correction) is right, then you just have to go on : you must have $a=-1$, $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=p+1$. so $P(x)=x^2-(p+3)x+2(p+1)$ ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assume the quadratic to be $a(x-p)(x-q)$ having positive roots p and q.

The sum of coefficients is $a(1-p-q+pq)$ = $a(p-1)(q-1)$.

For this to be prime, any two out of a,$(p-1)$ or $(q-1)$ be 1 and the other must be prime.

Therefore, at least one out of p or q will be $24.
This proves the first part.

Now, figure out $a(x-p)(x-2)=-55$

We shall take a=$1$ (as both roots are not same)

We end with $(x-p)(x-2)=-55$

Now, the factors should one out of $(-11,5) , (11,-5), (-5,11)$ or $(5,-11)$

Here, $(-11,5)$ and $(-5,11)$ give $p=18$

while $(11,-5) $ and $(5,-11)$ give $p=-9$

Since, p is a positive root.

Therefore p should be $18$ and the value of k is $7$ or $13$

Comment: May I know why my answer was downvoted?